# How to get the font style of a blank cell of excel in Java, Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache, fonts, apache-poi

I would like to capture the font (include font-size, font-family,  font-color, font-weight, etc.) of a **blank cell** in excel with Java.
  In other words, the **blank cell** has a certain font format (Not default font format), and i want setCellValue(theblankcell) without font format been changed.
  Because the cell is a blank cell, when i use getCellSytle(), it throws java.lang.NullPointerException runtime exception.
  I am using Apache POI 3.14. How can I do?
  Here is my code:

```
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");  
    CellStyle cellstyle = sheet1.getRow(2).getCell(0).getCellStyle();  
    Cell cell = null;  
    if (sheet1.getRow(2) != null){  
        Row row = sheet1.getRow(2);  
        if (row.getCell(0) != null) {  
            cell = row.getCell(0);  
        }  
        else {  
            cell = row.createCell(0);  
        }  
    }  
    else{  
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(2);  
        if (row.getCell(0) != null) {  
            cell = row.getCell(0);  
        }  
        else {  
            cell = row.createCell(0);  
        }  
    }  
    cell.setCellValue("test");  
    cell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: "when i use getCellSytle(), it throws java.lang.NullPointerException runtime exception": Then the cell object must be null. Please show the code how you get the cell object.

Comment: @AxelRichter I had added the code in the question above . I want to capture the font format even if the cell is a blank one.  What should i do? Please give some advice, thanks.

Comment: @ouuo: Sorry, can't reproduce. If cell `A3` in sheet `Sheet1` has a style applied, then `sheet1.getRow(2).getCell(0)` will **not** be null.